# Script in crontab only partially executed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, crontab

**My scenario:**

I've some python scripts on a raspberry pi. They behave like a service, they run forever without exiting and process signals. They are meant to run in the background, writing some values to a MariaDB. They run unattended, without a logged in user.

However, sometimes they crash. I'm not sure why and to me it looks like it's really hard to find out what happens (random crashes, no pattern, no clue, sometimes they run for months, sometimes they crash every day).

As the signals this scripts deal with are not really important, i'd love to just:

1. write a shell script that kills all running python scripts and
   starts them again
2. use crontab to run this script twice a day, so if
   something crashes i don't lose too much data and i don't have to
   care about checking and restarting them

I've written the shell script "restart.sh" and executing it in bash works great:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
kill $(pgrep python3)
sleep 2
nohup python3 script1.py &
sleep 2
nohup python3 script2.py &
sleep 2
nohup python3 script3.py &
sleep 2
exit
```

I've also modified my crontab with `sudo crontab -e`, containing this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

0 9 * * * /home/pi/restart.sh
0 15 * * * /home/pi/restart.sh
```

**My Problem:**

Testing the crontab, i can see that the `restart.sh` is executed but only the first command, the `kill` command, works. All running python3 scripts are killed, but not started again.

I tried adding `PATH` and `SHELL`, as that seems to be common problems, but that didn't change anything.

I also tried first to edit `crontab -e` without `sudo`, same problem.

What am i missing here? Why aren't the `nohup` commands executed like they are if i run `./restart.sh` manually in the terminal? What can i do to get this scripts started using crontab?

Comment: what's the purpose of sleep 2 along with &

Comment: @alecxs: `&` starts the script in background, `nohup` allone does not do that. `sleep 2` is just a delay of 2 seconds between the commands - maybe not really needed, but as some of the scripts need a moment to fully launch on the raspberry, i thought it can't hurt.

Comment: Using `&` in a non-interactive script without `wait` is always wrong (in some sense). Another recommendation: Avoid outdated `cron`, it has no place in the 20s of the 21. century. Use [`systemd` `.timer` units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) instead. They will give you precise success / failure tracking, proper log management and retention, configurable retries on failures, [security hardening](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/systemd-service-strengthening), handling of dependencies on (other) services and system states and **much** more.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek: How could `wait` be any help with `&` for a script that is intended to never finish? I might have a look at the mentioned `systemd.timer_units`, but honestly - i have no need for anything else than running a script twice a day, exactly what `cron` was made for. But if that helps to start this scripts it might be worth a try.

Comment: When something is not supposed to finish, then `systemd` is exactly the right way to manage it. With `&` there will always be issues around `SIGHUP`, around `loginctl enable-linger` etc., whereas `systemd` will get the environment for long-running processes set up correctly.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek: I don't really understand what you say. I have no problem with `SIGHUP` at all. I also have no clue what you try to explain with `loginctl enable-linger`, never heard of this, never had any issue where that came up. I want to run scripts and i tried to use `cron`. Cron is capable of running scripts, i thought? The script actually is started by cron, but not working correct. Do you have any idea what could cause that problem? It feels like i state that i have a problem with my bike and you keep saying "then drive by car instead"...

Comment: @xph You say “I can’t exceed 60 km/h with my bike”, to which I respond “yes, that’s normal, you need a motor vehicle for that”. If you want to see when, how and why your processes crash, `systemd` will do all the bookkeeping, logging and (if desired) restarting for you. Investigating the issue without getting `systemd` and proper service management involved sounds like reinventing the wheel. Problems like “I left some processes running and have no clue what happened to them” are one of the reasons why `systemd` was implemented.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek: You miss the point that i don't care why or when this python scripts crashes. They crash, it's fine. Yes, changing the complete method of running scripts might work. But i still believe what i'm trying to do here is not wanting to "exceed 60 km/h with my bike" and you can't provide any information to my origin question. You don't provide any helpful information at all on _how_ one could start a script twice a day using your mentioned method. Maybe you want to write an answer that shows how `systemd` could be used for that? Would be more helpful than "you are doing this wrong".

Comment: @xph I did provide [the necessary information](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) in my very first comment. There is extensive documentation covering the topic and starting a script twice a day is one of the very typical use cases. I don’t intend to write an answer with exact unit files, mainly because superuser is not a coding service. You got advice, take it or leave it — that’s all up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be cleaner to use pkill rather than pgrep but I don't think that's the problem.

I'm not sure from the information you supply precisely why your script isn't working as expected (it looks OK to me).

However I'm not sure using '&' in scripts called from  cron commands is the right thing to do. My first alternative suggestion would be to use the fact that cron natively runs things in the background, and have a separate cron job per python script rather than doing it all at once.

If I understand correctly, the symptom is that the python programs crash completely rather than hanging, and on the assumption it would be preferable to keep then running if they are happy, you could use a start-if-not-running script (I use bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$( ps -ef | grep -ic "$1" )
if [ $value -lt 2 ]
then
    python3 "$1"
fi
```

and then in your crontab:

```
15 * * * * bash /path/to/script/start-if-not-running.bash script1.py
30 * * * * bash /path/to/script/start-if-not-running.bash script2.py
45 * * * * bash /path/to/script/start-if-not-running.bash script3.py
```

Explanation:

`ps -ef` searches the entire command line of the process table (pgrep and pkill by default only search the first 13 characters)

`$value -lt 2` means if there are less than two matches then go ahead and start a new script (there will always be one match - that of the grep command itself)

I'd also strongly recommend making sure your raspberry pi emails you the outputs from cron commands if you haven't got that set up already (e.g. https://medium.com/swlh/setting-up-gmail-and-other-email-on-a-raspberry-pi-6f7e3ad3d0e) as an aid to debugging.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! To be more specific: I've seen both, python programs crash and hangs. It seems like they crash more often, but they could also be hanging - that's why i want to kill running ones and restart them. But meanwhile i have the problem that the sensor hardware and wiring, that delivers the signals for the python programs, is literally crashed, beause someone ripped all apart by accident... So if i find the time, i'll need to re-build it. And then your mentioned things will be super helpful! I'm sure this helps me a lot to get this working better. Thanks!